# Check words that start and end with same letter in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have written the code print only those words greater then length 5.
Now i want to print words that start and end with same letter.
Please note that it should be done in C# using regex library.
Code to print words greater than 5.

```
String str="programing world is nooooooot funnnnnnn";

Regex reg=new Regex("^[a-zA-Z_\\w]\\w*$");

String[] words=str.Split(' ');

for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
{
String temp=words[i];
if(Regex.IsMatch(temp,@"[a-zA-Z]{5}"))
Console.Writeline(temp);
}
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to use the simple way (`if(str[0] == str[str.Length-1])`)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled this smells like a "do this programming test for me" situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use regex capturing group.

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(temp,@"^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]{3,}\1$"))
```

It should match the words which starts and endswith the same letter and the word must contain atleast 5 letters. For greater than 5 letters, just change the number 3 to 4.

Comment: Yes, this solution works with arbitrary language ; here a string starting and ending with the same character :

`/^(.).*\1$/`

Comment: yep, but for single char `^(.)(?:.*\1)?$` :-)

Comment: True. I missed this case :)