# Regexp: filtering a pattern enclosed by the same pattern

Tags: python, regex

Having a text sample of the following layout...

```
<​text text <​text text> text text>

<​text text> <text text text <text ​text text>
```

...i need to capture the `<​enclosed parts​>` as highlighted.

ᅠ

With a lazy quantifier, the regexp `<.*?>` returns...

> **<​text text <​text text>** text text>
>
> **<​text text>** **<​text text text text <​text text>**

...which misses the upper right part and wrongly includes the middle bottom part. I’ve also tried it with `<.[^<]*?>`, which does it right on the 2<sup>-nd</sup> row, but misses both left and right parts on the 1<sup>-st</sup>:

> <​text text **<​text text>** text text>
>
> **<​text text>** <​text text text text **<​text text>**

ᅠ

How would the regexp look to `<​work as above​>`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541043/check-words-that-start-and-end-with-same-letter-in-c-sharp/46541129#comment80036711_46541129
Use “grouping„ and `\1`.

Furthermore, regexp IS NOT a good tool to match XML syntaxic langages : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: Consider using a parser instead.

Comment: Fix as `<[^<>]*>`, but if you are dealing with HTML/XML, you definitely need a parser.

Comment: Unfortunately this produces the same result as my 2-nd try. Also, for clarification, this isn’t net markup language, but rather syntax which was used to label parts in an ordinary text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Pzo "(?:<(?:[^<]|[<].*[>])*>)*" /tmp/test1
```

> ```
> <​text text <​text text> text text><​text text><text ​text text>
> ```

$ cat /tmp/test1

> ```
> <​text text <​text text> text text>
>
> <​text text> <text text text <text ​text text>
> ```

or as an alternative drop the multiline processing

```
$ grep -Po "(?:<(?:[^<]|[<].*[>])*>)*" /tmp/test1
<​text text <​text text> text text>
<​text text>
<text ​text text>
```

Comment: parser smarsher

Comment: Does this really capture everything except the middle bottom part for you, as seen **`<highlighted>`** in the first box of my question..?

Comment: it's working as I have shown, which I think is what you want.  The second example in my answer shows the 3 capture groups found.

Comment: But what about two levels of embedding? What about three, or four?

Comment: you can add more nested bits as you want.  It depends on how much you hate writing parsers.

Comment: Very well, thank you! Simplifying your regexp somewhat to `<([^<>]|<.*>)*>`, which still works great for what i wanted, i am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Matching balanced parentheses (or other symbols that match and embed) is a classic case of something that **regular expressions cannot do on principle.** This is a well-known mathematical result, and is beyond dispute (e.g., see [exercise 1 here](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs172/sp09/s3.pdf), or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)). Of course you can write a regexp that can handle *one* level of embedding, or *two* levels of embedding, but the regular expression language simply cannot handle an unrestricted number of levels.

The truth is that today's "perl-style regular expressions" have enough extensions (such as the `\1` back-substitutions) that it is possible to hack something together, for *some* non-regular (as they are called) tasks... not sure if yours is included. But it's going to be ugly and complicated, and you run a risk that it'll blow up to exponential runtimes with the wrong input.

I recommend you put aside regular expressions, and write a loop that iterates over characters in your text and counts the embedding level. Simple, readable, and done in a single pass on your string, no backtracking:

```
starts = []
for i in range(len(text)):
if text[i] == "<":
    starts.append(i)
elif text[i] == ">" and len(starts) > 0:
    print(text[starts[-1]:i+1])
    starts.pop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. For this task i’m still more inclined to use regexps, such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541853/regexp-filtering-a-pattern-enclosed-by-the-same-pattern#comment80046644_46543010) well working one.

Comment: Suit yourself. I guess you never embed more than one level of brackets...